# How to check whether the path is relative or absolute in java?

Tags: java

I am developing a tool, which takes a path of an `xml` file. Now that path can be either relative or absolute. Inside the code, when I have only a string, is there a way to identify that the path is absolute or relative?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

How about [`File.isAbsolute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isAbsolute%28%29):

```
File file = new File(path);
if (file.isAbsolute()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wished there was an apache-commons one liner for it, but there isn't

Comment: @FedericoBonelli According to ElMarce, a good one liner would be Paths.get(pathName).isAbsolute()

Answer (score 29):

There is another very similar way using [Paths operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html):

```
Path p = Paths.get(pathName); 
if (p.isAbsolute()) {
    ...
}
```